# Height adjustment issue of div according to the height of li tag in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying set the height of the navigation div for my navigation menu.But I am unable to get why it is not adjusting according to the li tag height.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Journeycook</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-top">
                <a href="#" class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" />
                </a>
                <div class="header-right">
                    <div class="call">
                        <img src="call.png" />
                        1-877-708-1505
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="act">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Flights</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
a img {
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
a img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul, li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper .header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
.header-top {
    margin: 3px 0;
}
.header-top a.logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 71px;
    width: 215px;
}
.header-right {
    float: right;
}
.call {
    color: #ffc620;
    font-size: 39px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.header-right .call img {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 48px;
}
.navigation {
    background: #04498E;
    border: 1px solid #002E73;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.navigation ul {
}
.navigation ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #1C61A6;
    float: left;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover {
    background: #ff8c04;
}
.navigation ul li .act {
    background: #ff8c04;
}
```

please experts tell me where i am going wrong

thanks

Comment: put your content inside the `body` tag

Comment: ohh yess got my first mistake I correct it but it is also  not working @aldanux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your navigation DIV is not adjusting to your ul is because of the float you put on it, use `clear:both` after the ul tag float so your nav div knows to adjust itself

You do not need to declare height on your navigation, if you do it will be fixed height

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the height for the navigation, simply change the following line and it will work fine:

```
.navigation { background: #04498E; border: 1px solid #002E73; border-radius: 6px; height:39px; }
```

Comment: but it have to to adjust height according to the height of li tag then why i define height for navigation div? this is not the issue. I can set it sir but why it is not working i want to know it please check my css

Answer (score 0):

got the solution :)

I forget to add clearfix div after ul tag here is the correct html for navigation div

```
<div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="act">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Flights</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
```